# Is there a way I can design the radio button

Tags: html, input

How to style the following HTML element -

```css
.input-box input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #0DFF92;
}

.input-box input[type=radio]:checked ~ label{
  color: #0DFF92;
}

.input-box input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 5px solid #0DFF92;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'> 
  <div class="input-container"> 
   <div class="input-box"> 
    <input type="radio" id="fiction" name="selector"> 
    <label for="fiction">Fiction</label> 
    <div class="check"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="input-box"> 
   <input type="radio" id="non-fiction" name="selector"> 
   <label for="non-fiction">Non-fiction</label> 
   <div class="check"></div> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

such that when the custom check button is clicked it changes color along side with the label.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `appearance: none;` to your CSS. This removes the default styling and allows you to change it.

Example:

```css
.input-box input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  appearance: none;
  background: #0DFF92;
}
```

Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#:%7E:text=%7D%0A%0Ainput%20%7B-,appearance%3A%20none%3B,-border%2Dradius%3A)